# Appending variable in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, uwp

I am trying to insert variable in my string, but it is giving me Syntax error.

```
  ',' expected
```

Don't know what I am missing here. Below is what I am trying to do:

```
  int var1 = 10;
  string name = "somename";

  string mystring = @"{ ""value"" : ""someval"", ""id"" : " + var1 + ", ""name"" : " + name + " }");
```

Expected Output:

```
{ "value" : "someval", "id" : "10", "name" : "somename"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted:

```
int var1 = 10;
string name = "somename";

string mystring = @"{ ""value"" : ""someval"", ""id"" : """+ var1 + @""" , ""name"" : """+ name + @"""}";
Console.WriteLine(mystring);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
{ "value" : "someval", "id" : "10", "name" : "somename"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When building up strings with variables it usually is a lot more readable to use a format string:

```
string mystring = string.Format(
    @"{{ ""value"" : ""someval"", ""id"" : ""{0}"", ""name"" : ""{1}"" }}", var1, name);
```

In C# 6, this can be expressed even simpler using [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
string mystring = $"{{ \"value\" : \"someval\", \"id\" : \"{var1}\", \"name\" : \"{name}\" }}";
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `"` around name and id: `@"{ ""value"" : ""someval"", ""id"" : ""{0}"", ""name"" : ""{1}"" }"`

Comment: It's throwing System.Format Exception :
{ "value" : "someval", "id" : "{0}", "name" : "{1}" }

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the double quotes:

```
var finalString = "{ \"value\" : \"someval\", \"id\" : " + var1 + "\"name\" : " + var2 + " }";
```

Or use string.Concat

```
var finalString = string.Concat("\"value\" : \"someval\", \"id\" :", var1, "\"name\" :", var2, "}");
```